# Could not resolve archetype in maven using Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-oxygen

[image: error log screenshot]

I'm not using any proxy, using the hotspot from my mobile to connect to internet, using Maven Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Could you please add the problem details to your question? Which Java version do you use?

Comment: @howlger I'm using java 1.8